# Manually trigger notification sound in iOS

Tags: ios

Is is possible to emulate the sound or vibration of a notification in iOS? If yes, how?

My target is to trigger the same kind of effect for the user if the application is left opened on a table corner, to inform her that something has happened.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger a vibration effect calling:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
```

This will produce a default vibration of 4 milliseconds whenever you want.
Don't forget to import AudioToolbox

```
 #import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use NSNotificationCenter to dispatch notifications, and you can also emulate a vibration programmatically, won't it solve your requirement?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it would but I don't consider this as clean. I would like something like: that looks like "triggerUserNotification()" that would check wether or not the user asked for vibrations or allowed sound and play what's relevant.

Comment: If you use NSNotificationCenter, your notification can be configured to play a soundName, applicationIconBadgeNumber and alertAction. And rest all properties will default.

Comment: Do you know if this notification will fire even if the app is opened?

Comment: No, when the app is open you can not use NSNotificationCenter to send notifications, instead you use UIAlertView. You can not always find a clean solution on iPhone.